# Countability of a set of partitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I'm trying to figure out if "the set of all possible partitions of the interval [1,0] is countable or uncountable."

Comment: Do you mean [0,1] and not [1,0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is uncountable. For every $x \in [0,1]$, of which there are uncountably many such $x$, $\{ \{x\}, [0,1] \setminus \{x\}\}$ is a partition of $[0,1]$.